# Which motor is suitable for generating a constant pressure on objects?

Tags: robotic-arm, motor

I want to build a simple arm that can generate a pressure on a small object (a force of 50-100 gram is enough) and let go of it very quickly. Which motor can be used for this?

Comment: Rather than focusing on the motor needed, the better question would be what type of motor control is needed to achieve your task.

Comment: More importantly how does one intend to implement the holding of said spring then it's release?

Comment: I can relax "pushing a spring" to "pushing an object".